# Adding a box-shadow blur to only one side of an element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to add a blur to only one side of a div using box-shadow?

What I am trying to achieve is a shadow with **no** width, just blur on only one side of a div. In my example I try to apply it to the bottom but the side really shouldn't matter.

I tried have using `box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px #000000;` however using this method the shadow does not cover the whole length on the bottom of the div.

```css
#bg {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px #000000;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Only HTML and CSS solutions please.

Comment: Why don't you use a bottom border? it will trick the eye and disguise itself as a slight shadow.

Comment: Another way to achieve this would be a positioned pseudo element, with a gradient background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an after element and stretch it a little:

```css
#bg {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

#box:after {
  content:'';
  display:block; 
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
  top:0;
  left:-4px;
  right:-4px;
  bottom:0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px #000000;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:relative;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for bottom positioned `box-shadow`

```
.your_class {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```

You can also read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow to understand how the `box-shadow` works

Answer (score 0):

```css
#bg {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no readily available way to do precisely what you seek, at least not using a single `box-shadow`. Remember, the CSS `box-shadow` property accepts multiple comma-delimited entries, so this is your best bet if you're committed to using them. In the example below, I'm simply using two copies of the same `box-shadow` value with one difference: I've offset the first horizontally toward the left by `2.5px` and the other toward the right by positive `2.5px`. Additionally, I've added opacity to the color (due to mitigate the darkening effect of overlapping shadows).

```css
#bg {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #EEE;
}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: -2.5px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50),
              2.5px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: Yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#bg {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

#box:after {
  content:'';
  display:block; 
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
  bottom:0px;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0, #9C9C9C),
    color-stop(0.22, #EEEEEE)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #9C9C9C 0%, #EEEEEE 22%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #9C9C9C 0%, #EEEEEE 22%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #9C9C9C 0%, #EEEEEE 22%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #9C9C9C 0%, #EEEEEE 22%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9C9C9C 0%, #EEEEEE 22%);
height:10px;
width:100%;

}

#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:relative;
  background: yellow;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lfa4z5b4/